# asp.net textbox changed event not fired when textbox value is changed in jquery code

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have three text boxes, first name txtFirstName, last name txtLastName and AD User ID txtADUserID. Whenever first name or last name is changed, I am assigning AD user id value in Jquery code. I see in browser that ADUserID textbox value is changed.

PROBLEM: I need to check if user id already exist in txtADUserID's ontextchanged server side event. OnTextChanged event is NOT fired at all and postback is also not raised.

ASP.net code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtADUserID" runat="server" MaxLength="255" ClientIDMode="Static" OnTextChanged="txtADUserID_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtFirstName").on('change', function () {
           $('#txtADUserID').val($('#txtFirstName').val().charAt(0) + $('#txtLastName').val());
        });
        $("#txtLastName").on('change', function () {
           $('#txtADUserID').val($('#txtFirstName').val().charAt(0) + $('#txtLastName').val());
        });
    });
```

Code behind code:

```
    protected void txtADUserID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
// Raise an error if user already exist
         }
```

Comment: Do you know the server event isn't fired until the textbox loses focus?

Comment: yes, event is not fired even after tabbing out of the textbox

Comment: But if the user is typing in txtFirstName, they are not tabbing out of txtADUserID which is what the server event is attached to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing text through javascript without user interaction that is why you did not get server side `postback`. You can add a `button` and bind server side `event` to that button and perform button `click` when you need postback. Also store the `value` of `textbox` in some `hidden field` as you will not get the updated `textbox` value on server side.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#txtFirstName").on('change', function () {
           $('#txtADUserID').val($('#txtFirstName').val().charAt(0) + $('#txtLastName').val());
           $('#buttonId').click();  
      });
      $("#txtLastName").on('change', function () {
           $('#txtADUserID').val($('#txtFirstName').val().charAt(0) + $('#txtLastName').val());
           $('#buttonId').click();
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I already did exactly the same with an anchor instead of a button. i have required field validators on my page and they were not letting postback happen. So, I added causesvalidation=false to the anchor and everything looks good again. Your answer reaffirmed that the problem is elsewhere other than the jquery code. I ended up using a button with no text. Thanks!